# How to select all the rows with the same name and not only the first one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyexcel

This is the xls file :

```
moto    5   2   45
moto    2   4   43
coche   8   54  12
coche   43  21  6
coche   22  14  18
```

And this is the code working with pyexcel library:

```
import pyexcel as pe
data = pe.get_sheet(file_name="vehiculo.xls")
sheet = pe.Sheet(data, name_rows_by_column=0)
sheet.row.select(['coche'])
sheet.save_as("output.xls")
```

it returns only the fisrt row with name 'coche':

```
coche   8   54  12
```

And I want all the rows with the name "coche".

Any idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apology for the fact that the function 'select' didn't work as intended. It didn't work because the rest of the row becomes coche-1, coche-2(you can check it out by `print(s)`). This is the default behaviour on row names that has the same name. Will change in the future.

For now, to get your use case to work, you can use pyexcel==0.3.0+ with this statement:

```
...
>>> sheet = pe.Sheet(data) # , name_rows_by_column=0)
>>> del sheet.row[lambda row_inde,row: row[0] != 'coche']
...
```

Here is [the documentation](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration_guide.html#updated-filter-function) on this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the data:

```
import pyexcel
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)
data = pe.get_sheet(file_name="vehiculo.xls")
for row in data.rows():
   results[row[0]] += row[1:]
```

You'll get the following:

```
>>> results['moto']
[5L, 2L, 45L, 2L, 4L, 43L]
```